Discourse bell icon highlights
In Discourse (an application that anyone can use to generate and run a forum), when I click my profile picture (avatar) in the top-right corner of the screen, it shows a column of icons, and to the left of that column a list of highlighted links.
What are these? Why are they shown to me? Why are they highlighted? I wan’t pinged/tagged/replied in any of them. Why doesn’t this only show notifications that need my attention?
I don’t see any relevant configuration under preferences/notifications. Under preferences/tracking, all “Categories” are empty.

What is a "Discource forum"? Is this software you install on your own computer, or is this an internet forum running particular software? Please note that questions about the software running on your computer are on topic here, but questions about internet forums are very probably not on topic here.

I’ve added a link the my question above now. Discourse is an app that generates a forum that runs on any server.

Have you checked the support documentation regarding this? Have you clicked the icons/links to see where they take you?

I suggest you ask about that on https://meta.discourse.org

Yes, I looked for an answer before posting here. This is my place of last resort.
